# How to remove git unstageg changes resulted from removing directories?

Tags: eclipse, git

I had many subdirectories under workspace directory that was under git configuration.   I moved some of these subdirectories to another directory.  As a result I see thousands of unstaged changed from these deletions, I can watch them from Eclipse.  Git diff shows “deleted file mode 100644”.

How to remove these unstaged changes resulted from removing directories?

Comment: In Git directories are only used as file location (e. g. you can not commit an empty directory). Moving is technically deleting + adding. Which of unstaged changes do you have? Were the moved files committed before?

Comment: I have thousands of unstaged changes.  Some of the files were commited, some were not

Comment: Right-click and choose _Team > Ignore_ to ignore a file or a whole directory tree. If the files have been already commited, you have to commit the deletion of the old location.

Comment: right click on what?

Comment: Right-click in _Project/Package Explorer_, _Navigator_, etc. In the _Git Staging_ view you have first switch to _Tree_ or _Compact Tree_ presentation mode (view menu: _Presentation > ..._) to have directories which can be right-clicked.

Answer (score 0):

IF you move elements of a repository outside, it is expected for the Git repo to list those element as being deleted.

You should simply [add them (`Team > Add`), and commit them](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Committing_Changes) (recording their deletion).
Once you have done a commit, those files won't show up anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to run `git add -p`, which interactively prompts you to stage *all* changes in the working directory.

In general, there is a lot more flexibility using `git` from the command-line than you'll get from within an IDE.